# Slider used in Xamarin.froms to control value

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, model-binding, freshmvvm

I'm adding a slider into my xamarin app, but im using view models to capture values. How can I move the slider on the GUI and show the value incrementing up and down and then capture its value?

or is there a way I can include the "MySlider_ValueChanged" event and apply it to the view model page rather than the content page code behind file?

Comment: you need to bind the Slider's value property to a property in your model

Comment: are you using MVVM ? or Prism ?

Comment: i am using MVVM

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way I can include the "MySlider_ValueChanged" event and apply it to the view model page rather than the content page code behind file?

You have to find a BindableProperty which could be bound inside view model(`ICommand`) ,it should do the same work as the event `ValueChanged` .

#### For exmaple

We could handle `Tapped` event of `TapGestureRecognizer` in page code behind , we also could create new `ICommand` inside view model , and bind it with `Command` of TapGestureRecognizer .

However, Slider does not have command whose function is detecting the value changed , there is only [DragStartedCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.slider.dragstartedcommand?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Slider_DragStartedCommand) and [DragCompletedCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.slider.dragcompletedcommand?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Slider_DragCompletedCommand) ,
so the only solution is to trigger your method inside the setter method of Value .

Xaml

```
<Slider  Value="{Binding CurrentProgress}" />
```

View Model

```
public double CurrentProgress
{
    get { return currentProgress; }
    set
    {
        currentProgress = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentProgress");
        YourMethod(value);
    }
}
```

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25141043/8187800.